# Calculate required position to keep object centered when camera is rotated

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

I always want to keep an object in the center of view of a camera.
The object can not change its position.

The camera can be rotated.
The camera can move up and down.
The object should always be centered in the view of the camera.

So when I rotate the camera by -45°, I would like to know the Y position of the camera at which the rotated camera would still directly face the object.

I know the "horizontal" distance between the camera and the object (as this never changes), and I know the angle of the camera.

How could the "required camera position Y value" be calculated?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: 1. Object can be a child 2. Move object instead of camera and use lookAt. 3. Can object be placed as UI?!

Comment: @ValeraKvip Thank you. I want to use pure math to solve this.I have clarified my post.

Comment: Ok i understood, but it's can be interesting https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html

Comment: I can't test it: x = R * cos(a); y = R * sin(a); R - distance between camera and obj, a - angle between zero rotation and target rotation

Comment: Thank you, I'm not sure if I apply it correctly. Just checking. The current results are very funny.

Comment: @ValeraKvip If the camera is placed left to the object, then "distance" is negative. If the camera is placed right to the object, then "distance" is positive. The resulting "y" is very different then. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this code works for me:

```
//Distance between object and camera. Y-axis is pointing up, so we use x and z coordinates.
float R = Vector2.Distance(new Vector2(obj.position.x, obj.position.z),
                            new Vector2(camera.transform.position.x, camera.transform.position.z));
// Lets find rotation from zero to target angle   
float rAngle = Mathf.Deg2Rad * (camera.transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y + angle );
// Using minus cause when we rotate camera to the "right" we have to move it to the"left"
        float x = -R * Mathf.Sin(rAngle);
        float y = -R * Mathf.Cos(rAngle);

// Apply changes.
camera.transform.position = new Vector3(x, camera.transform.position.y, y);
Vector3 cameraRotation = new Vector3(0,  angle,0);
camera.transform.Rotate(cameraRotation);
```

And as i said you easily can use https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html